# Why there is an error "The requested URL could not be retrieved" with angular app?

Tags: angular, squid, npm-start

I'm trying to run some angular app. After successfully `npm install`, i'm run `npm start`.
Following is result:
[image: result of the nmp start]

But I'm get following error when trying open in browser `localhost:4200`

[image: Connection refused]

I'm confused because on another  pc it is work without errors. Where can lie the error?

Comment: looks like you have a proxy server (squid cache) enabled on your pc. Try disabling it. It is not a problem with angular

Comment: Instead of npm start,
Use  " ng serve --host <YOUR IP ADDRESS>"
And then access the URL <YOUR IP ADDRESS>:4200 , that should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IE.
Internet Options -> Connections -> LAN Settings -> click Advanced and add localhost to Exceptions.
It is fix this problem.

Comment: I had `http_proxy` env variable set in my PC. So had to set `no_proxy` env variable to `localhost`

Answer (score 1):

On my case, I forgot that I have an entry on my host file at:

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
```

I just removed it and everything worked as expected.